# Memory barrier scope

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm not sure what's the scope of `std::memory_order_release` or `std::memory_order_acquire` memory barriers. Below is an example taken from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order). I tweaked the code to make my point:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

std::atomic<std::string*> ptr;

void producer()
{
  std::string* p  = new std::string("Hello");

  ptr.store(p, std::memory_order_release);
}

bool acquire(std::string* p2)
{
  while (!(p2 = ptr.load(std::memory_order_acquire)));

  return p2 != nullptr;
}

void consumer()
{
  std::string* p2 {nullptr};

  // while (!(p2 = ptr.load(std::memory_order_acquire))); // prints "makes sense"
  assert(acquire(p2)); // prints "what's going on?"

  if (p2 == nullptr)
  {
    std::cout << "what's going on?" << std::endl;
  }
  else
  { 
    std::cout << "makes sense" << std::endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::thread t1(producer);
  std::thread t2(consumer);
  t1.join(); t2.join();
}
```

The output of the above code is `what's going on?`

I'm familiar (not expert) with memory barriers. From the test above I have the following questions:

1. The `std::memory_order_acquire` used in `acquire()` function only is used for the scope of `acquire()`, based on the output of the program since uncommenting `while(...)` prints the expected output "makes sense". Does this make sense? am I missing anything?
2. How is it possible to print "what's going on?", the `assert(acquire(p2))` makes it clear p2 is not `nullptr`, but somehow it reads the `nullptr` value in the `if` conditional. I'm not an expert in out of order execution rules, but I'd expect that `p2 = nullptr` is honored before calling `acquire()`, `since acquire()` depends on it.

Comment: Has nothing to do with memory semantics. In one case, you're directly assigning to the pointer you're printing, in the other case you're not.

Comment: You have two different `std::string* p2`.  They are not the same variable!  You are assigning to one and then checking if the other is still null.

Comment: @Drew Dormann thank you! silly mistake from my part. I'll edit the question again.

Comment: @AdvSphere I've posted an answer.  Please post a **new** question if you have a new, different question.

Comment: @Drew Dormann will do! thanks again!

Comment: memory barriers have no "scope". the `ptr.store(p, std::memory_order_release);` is synchronization point with `ptr.load(std::memory_order_acquire)`. all  writes in `producer` before this point visible in `consumer` after it view result of `ptr` written by producer

Comment: assert(acquire(p2)); // will be skipped in release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. The `std::memory_order_acquire` used in `acquire()` function only is used for the scope of acquire()

No.  It applies to *the thread* and is not bound by any function boundaries.

> 2. How is it possible to print "what's going on?"

Because you are modifying a **copy** of the pointer.  Change:

```
bool acquire(std::string* p2)
```

to:

```
bool acquire(std::string*& p2)
```

to make the function **reference** the same pointer that's being passed to it.